# Request an URL and fill the content of the x-ww-form-urlencoded file into variable

Tags: javascript, url, request

I am trying to request an external URL with 'GET' to receive the content. I would like to continue to work with this response. But unfortunately it doesn't work, maybe you can help me. My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo">
<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=wbSwFU6tY1c", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should probably use the [official YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) for any such request.

Comment: That URL does not support CORS. Use a proxy on server you control or third party service or as mentioned use the proper API

Comment: Hi Jeto, thanks for the answer. Yes , I know about the API. I am just wondering, how to solve this issue, in case of such an URL. It doesn't have to be an Youtube Link. It could be also another one. Thanks.

Comment: When I run a GET request (for example with this [Online GET request tool](https://www.httpdebugger.com/tools/ViewHttpHeaders.aspx)), than I am able to read the response content. It's not like downloading anything before, just displaying the content. And this is exactly what I want to do. Just write the 'response content' of this URL to a variable in JS and work with it later.

Comment: @charlietfl could you please give me some keywords, for what I do have to search, if I would like to do it with 'proxy on server' or a third party service? Thanks.

Comment: Search *"ajax proxy"* and include whatever language you have access to on your server